# Remove Subdomains from Form Post

Tags: php, forms

How would I go about extracting just the base URl from a long string that was inputted into a form?

Example: 
User inputs: `http://stackoverflow.com/question/ask/asdfasneransea`
Program needs just: `http://stackoverflow.com` and not `/question/ask/asdfasneransea`

What is the easist way to do this using PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use [`parse_url()`](http://www.php.net/parse_url)

```
$url = parse_url('http://example.com/foo/bar');
$host = $url['host']; // example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the parse_url function to get the separate parts of the URL, then reassemble the parts you are looking for.